# perlでファイルの指定文字列を取り出し、変数へ格納

Tags: perl

あるファイル（仮にsample.txt）の一行目には三つの数字があります。数字と数字の間に半角スペースが入ってます。三つの数字を正規表現で取り出し、それぞれ変数A、B、Cに格納する方法はありますか

```
20 31 7
abcdefg
あいうえお
...
```

自分はこのように考えています。うまくいかなかったです。

```
print"ファイル名を指定してください！";
  chomp(my $file = <STDIN>);
  open (IN, $file) or die;

  my $para = qr/(\d+)\s(\d+)\s(\d+)/x;

  if (<IN>=~ /$para/) {
     my $A = $1;
     my $B = $2;
     my $C = $3;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

質問の通り「正規表現」を使うなら以下のように自分なら書きますが、今回の場合なら「半角スペース区切り」でsplitする方法もあります。

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $file = "sample.txt";

open(FH,"<$file") or die;
my $line = <FH>;
chomp($line);

## 正規表現を使用して取り出す
 my ($A,$B,$C) = $line =~ /(\d+) (\d+) (\d+)/;
##
## or
##   "半角スペース"区切りでsplitを使う
#my ($A,$B,$C) = split(/ /,$line);

print "A: $A\n";
print "B: $B\n";
print "C: $C\n";
```